# How to get a bone's weight using a json file

Tags: gltf

I am trying to get the weight for every bone using a gltf json file but i dont know how

here is the json file i am trying to get the weight from:

```
{
  "accessors": [
    {
      "bufferView": 0,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 317,
      "max": [
        10.570027351379395,
        15.918471336364746,
        6.125584125518799
      ],
      "min": [
        -2.611180305480957,
        -1.9711413383483887,
        -7.055622577667236
      ],
      "type": "VEC3"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 1,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 317,
      "type": "VEC3"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 2,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 317,
      "type": "VEC2"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 3,
      "componentType": 5121,
      "count": 317,
      "type": "VEC4"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 4,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 317,
      "type": "VEC4"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 5,
      "componentType": 5123,
      "count": 768,
      "type": "SCALAR"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 6,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 5,
      "type": "MAT4"
    }
  ],
  "asset": {
    "generator": "Khronos glTF Blender I/O v1.5.17",
    "version": "2.0"
  },
  "bufferViews": [
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteLength": 3804,
      "byteOffset": 0
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteLength": 3804,
      "byteOffset": 3804
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteLength": 2536,
      "byteOffset": 7608
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteLength": 1268,
      "byteOffset": 10144
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteLength": 5072,
      "byteOffset": 11412
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteLength": 1536,
      "byteOffset": 16484
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteLength": 320,
      "byteOffset": 18020
    }
  ],
  "buffers": [
    {
      "byteLength": 18340,
      "uri": "manoe.bin"
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "mimeType": "image/png",
      "name": "Material_002_baseColor",
      "uri": "Material_002_baseColor.png"
    }
  ],
  "materials": [
    {
      "doubleSided": true,
      "name": "Material.001",
      "pbrMetallicRoughness": {
        "baseColorTexture": {
          "index": 0
        },
        "metallicFactor": 0,
        "roughnessFactor": 0.4000000059604645
      }
    }
  ],
  "meshes": [
    {
      "name": "Cone.001",
      "primitives": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "JOINTS_0": 3,
            "NORMAL": 1,
            "POSITION": 0,
            "TEXCOORD_0": 2,
            "WEIGHTS_0": 4
          },
          "indices": 5,
          "material": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "nodes": [
    {
      "name": "Bone.004",
      "rotation": [
        0.17750653624534607,
        -2.8648443617385055e-8,
        -0.9102426171302795,
        0.37409862875938416
      ],
      "scale": [
        1.000000238418579,
        1,
        1
      ],
      "translation": [
        -4.411018750261064e-8,
        0.8281745314598083,
        1.4894996525072202e-7
      ]
    },
    {
      "children": [
        0
      ],
      "name": "Bone.002",
      "rotation": [
        0.2184765785932541,
        -0.2617807984352112,
        -0.7560504078865051,
        0.558682918548584
      ],
      "scale": [
        1.0000003576278687,
        1,
        1
      ],
      "translation": [
        6.093483762015239e-8,
        0.8281747698783875,
        -1.283853023892334e-9
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Bone.003",
      "rotation": [
        -0.4916436970233917,
        7.804754176277129e-8,
        -0.14189021289348602,
        0.8591586947441101
      ],
      "scale": [
        1,
        1.0000001192092896,
        0.9999999403953552
      ],
      "translation": [
        -2.4224684125329077e-7,
        0.8281750679016113,
        -2.68131650216219e-9
      ]
    },
    {
      "children": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "name": "Bone.001",
      "rotation": [
        -0.11594496667385101,
        0.08448944985866547,
        -0.5036448836326599,
        0.8519155383110046
      ],
      "scale": [
        1.000000238418579,
        0.9999995827674866,
        1
      ],
      "translation": [
        -1.357730283757519e-8,
        1.0000007152557373,
        -3.471412068391244e-14
      ]
    },
    {
      "children": [
        3
      ],
      "name": "Bone",
      "rotation": [
        2.3709270635663415e-7,
        2.8494374859633353e-8,
        6.9593789722201e-15,
        1
      ],
      "scale": null,
      "translation": null
    },
    {
      "mesh": 0,
      "name": "Cone.001",
      "skin": 0
    },
    {
      "children": [
        5,
        4
      ],
      "name": "ArmatureBase",
      "scale": [
        5.400000095367432,
        5.400000095367432,
        5.400000095367432
      ]
    }
  ],
  "samplers": [
    {
      "magFilter": 9729,
      "minFilter": 9987
    }
  ],
  "scene": 0,
  "scenes": [
    {
      "name": "Scene",
      "nodes": [
        6
      ]
    }
  ],
  "skins": [
    {
      "inverseBindMatrices": 6,
      "joints": [
        4,
        3,
        1,
        0,
        2
      ],
      "name": "ArmatureBase"
    }
  ],
  "textures": [
    {
      "sampler": 0,
      "source": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just search how to parse json file.[c++]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [glTF overview card](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/main/specification/2.0/figures/gltfOverview-2.0.0b.png) summarizes it nicely:

Every vertex can be associated with up to 4 joints, each with a given weight.
These are encoded in the components of the JOINTS_0 and WEIGHTS_0 accessors. In your case those are accessors 3 and 4 and bufferviews 3 and 4 with a component type of `byte` and `float`, respectively.

One more indirection into the `bufferViews` component here tells you where in the binary file to look.